# UnicodeEncodeError in Python 3 and BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, beautifulsoup

When running my codes, I get this error

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0303' in position 71: ordinal not in range(128)

This is my whole codes,

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from urllib.request import urlretrieve as uRet
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import urllib

for x in range(143, 608):
    myUrl = "example.com/" + str(x)
    try:
        uClient = uReq(myUrl)
        page_html = uClient.read()
        uClient.close()
        page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

        container = page_soup.findAll("div", {"id": "videoPostContent"})

        img_container = container[0].findAll("img")
        images = img_container[0].findAll("img")

        imgCounter = 0

        if len(images) == "":
            for image in images:
                print('Downloading image from ' + image['src'] + '...')
                imgCounter += 1
                uRet(image['src'], 'pictures/' + str(x) + '.jpg')
        else:
            for image in img_container:
                print('Downloading image from ' + image['src'] + '...')
                imgCounter += 1
                uRet(image['src'], 'pictures/' + str(x) + '_' + str(imgCounter) + '.jpg')
    except urllib.error.HTTPError:
        continue
```

**Tried Solutions:**

I tried adding `.encode/decode('utf-8')` and `.text.encode/decode('utf-8')` to `page_soup` but it gives this errors.

> AttributeError: 'str' / 'bytes' object has no attribute 'findAll' or

Comment: At what line is that error being thrown?

Comment: Converting page_soup into a string means that it no longer is a BeatifulSoup object.  So you can't use `findAll`.  What line is throwing the error?

Comment: at uRet() [that is the urlretrieve]

Comment: So one of the strings in there isn't encoded in a way that uRet understands.  I believe you want to `encode` any string before you put it in uRet.  Likely `images['src'].encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: Tried putting `.encode('utf-8)` in `images['src']` but it gives me: `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`

Comment: Do you know what the type of `images['src']` is then?  Looks like it's not even a string. So when you go to concatenate it with other strings, Python is trying to convert it into "ascii" and failing. If images['src'] is a byte array, then you need to use `decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: the type of `image['src']` is _string_

Answer (score 0):

At least one of the image src urls contain non-ascii characters, and `urlretrieve` is unable to process them.

```
>>> url = 'http://example.com/' + '\u0303'
>>> urlretrieve(url)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ...
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0303' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

You could try one of these approaches to get around this problem.

1. Assume that these urls are valid, and retrieve them using a library that has better unicode handling, like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).
2. Assume that the urls are valid, but contain unicode characters that must be escaped before passing to `urlretrieve`.  This would entail splitting the url into scheme, domain, path etc, quoting the path and any query parameters and then unsplitting; all the tools for this are in the [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.parse.html) package (but this is probably what requests does anyway, so just use requests).
3. Assume that these urls are broken and skip them by wrapping your `urlretrieve` calls with `try/except UnicodeEncodeError`